# In C, how can I change the memory address a pointer is pointing to?

Tags: c, pointers, memory, memory-management

So for example I have a char ** array that has 3 pointers.
Let's say:

```
array[0] has abc (points to "a", which lives in address 0x80033de0)
array[1] has def (points to "d", which lives in address 0x80033d)
array[2] has NULL
```

Assuming that I have copied the strings of array to a different a different memory location let's say

```
0x7ffffff8 has abc (points to "a")
0x7ffffffc has def (points to "d")
```

How can I change array[0] so that it points to 0x7ffffff8 instead of 0x80033de0?

And also array[1] so that it points to 0x7ffffffc instead of 0x80033d?

I've already tried different kinds of casting but haven't been able to get it to work.

EDIT:

Thanks for looking at my question everyone. The reason I asked this is because I'm working with kernel and I needed to copy arguments from kernel space to userspace. I thought I could do so by copying the arg strings to userspace then changing the memory address that the original args pointer point to in kernel space. I guess that was not a good idea.

Comment: What have you tried? You should just be able to do `array[0] = (char*)0x7FFFFFF8`

Comment: "I've already tried different kinds of casting but haven't been able to get it to work." - show us the code and errors then.

Comment: What are you *actually* trying to do? Do you want to have a deep copy of the `char**`? Do you want to have copy-aware structures? Please, explain a bit more.

Comment: The two answers so far assume that there's some significance to `0x7ffffff8`; I doubt that that's the case. Describe what you want to do rather than showing examples with specific meaningless memory addresses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have a char ** array that has 3 pointers

No, you don't. You have an array with three values. The values happen to be pointers. An array doesn't *have* pointers.

Suppose you allocate memory for this array (of pointers to char):

```
char **array = malloc( 3 * sizeof(char*)); // 3 values in the array
```

and then you allocate memory for each string:

```
array[0] = malloc(4 * sizeof(char) ); // 3 + 1 null terminator
array[1] = malloc(4 * sizeof(char) );
array[2] = 0;
```

finally you set the values for the strings themselves:

```
strcpy( array[0], "abc" );
strcpy( array[1], "def" );
```

Now you want to make a copy. A *deep* copy actually, because you not only allocate memory for a new array (of pointers to char) but you allocate memory for new strings as well.
You do exactly the same allocation:

```
char **array2 = malloc( 3 * sizeof(char*));
array2[0] = malloc(4 * sizeof(char) );
array2[1] = malloc(4 * sizeof(char) );
array2[2] = 0;
```

Now you copy the actual strings:

```
strcpy( array2[0], array[0] );
strcpy( array2[1], array[1] );
```

If your code differs from the one above, edit your question with more details.

The tricky part is making array[0] hold the address which is in array2[0] (same for array[1] and array2[1]). The problem comes from the fact that memory you allocate via `malloc` needs to be freed via `free`.

So you **can't** just do

```
array[0] = array2[0];
```

Because you've lost all references to the first string you allocated. That memory is *leaked*.

Instead do this:

```
free(array[0]);
array[0] = array2[0];
```

This frees the memory used for the first string and copies the address of the copy.

Now you have the same pointer (value) in two variables. This is also tricky because (when you no longer need it) you still need to free the memory allocated for the copy:

`free(array2[0])`

The *tricky* part is that `array[0]` now holds a pointer to freed memory, which can't be used. Using it will lead to bugs.

It would probably be a good idea not to have multiple variables (in the same scope) that hold the same pointer to allocated memory. That may make it difficult to reason about the validity of the pointer.

Answer (score 0):

`char ** array` is a pointer of pointers.
In this case, it gets assigned an array of char pointers, each of which contains the address of the first char of your eventual cstrings.

As such, you can just use the equal sign, as you would with an other regular pointer:

`array[0] = (char*)0x7ffffffc;`

`array[1] = (char*)0x80033d;`

Comment: No a `char**` is never *becomes* an array. It might point to the first element of an array. Read section 6 of the [comp.lang.c FAQ](http://www.c-faq.com/).

Comment: Better, but a `char**` isn't going to be "equivalent" to the address of a `char`.

Comment: A bit, but you're assuming that the hex addresses are meaningful. I know that's what the OP asked, but the solution to the OP's actual problem should just involve pointer assignments. It's hard to tell what the OP's problem actually is.

Comment: A few more observations: "pointer of pointers" doesn't make much sense; a `char**` is a pointer *to* a pointer. *"gets assigned an array of char pointers"* -- well, yes and no. You can do an assignment like `array = foo;`, where `foo` is an array of `char*` -- but the value of `foo` is converted to a pointer to the array's first element, and *that's* what's assigned to the (arguably misnamed) pointer object `array`. And since we're talking about C, not C++, there's no need for the term "cstrings"; they're just strings.

Answer (score -3):

Basically an array is a pointer to the start address. Thus array[n] is equal to *(array+n). If you want to move your whole array you could do something like

```
array = newPointer; //newPointer is something like char *newPointer;
//notice the array without brackets because you want the pointer!
```

Comment: Arrays in C are not assignable.

Comment: Arrays are not pointers. See section 6 of the [comp.lang.c FAQ](http://www.c-faq.com/).